# Mule ESB: 1st EE flow, and Console in Standalone version

Tags: eclipse, mule, esb

I have the following flow defined on a Community Edition Studio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:https="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https/current/mule-https.xsd">
    <db:generic-config name="Generic_Database_Configuration" url="jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/TEST:user=instuid;password=instpw;" driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" doc:name="Generic Database Configuration"/>
    <http:endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" method="POST" name="HTTP" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <flow name="test1Flow1" doc:name="test1Flow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP" contentType="application/json" keepAlive="true"  mimeType="application/json"/>
        <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

.. and after performing a "Right Click -> Run As from within the Studio I can get it to run

Then I can get the studio edition to run with the following command:

```
C:\curl> curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u anon:anon -d {"first":"Stev
en"} http://localhost:8081
{first:Steven}
```

So now I copy the test1.zip to the Standalone Enterprise Edition on Linux:

```
[root@x240perf2 apps]# cp /home/app/test1.zip .
[root@x240perf2 apps]# ls
default  default-anchor.txt  test1  test1-anchor.txt
```

Where test1 is a directory.

So I test the app, as follows

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u anon:anon -d {"first":"Steven"} http://localhost:8081
{first:Steven}[root@x240perf2 test1]#
```

So it is working.  I am happy except for one thing.

When I run this in the studio, I can see the folowing in the Console tab at the bvottom of the studio

```
INFO  2014-11-10 15:02:14,331 [[test1].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.04] org.mule.component.simple.LogComponent: 
********************************************************************************
* Message received in service: test1Flow1. Content is: '{first:Steven}'        *
********************************************************************************
```

Where can I see this information in the equivalent of the console from within the Standalone in Enterprise Edition ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a directory in the stand alone installation called "logs", where mule logs the console output.

so if you are in /apps directory you can execute

```
# tail -f ../logs/mule_ee.log
```

Also you can configure the logging properties (file name, rotation policy, etc) in the wrapper.conf file that is located in the /conf directory.